# SSL version error when cloning with TortoiseHG https mode

Tags: ssl, windows-7, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm using TortoiseHG on win7 64b to clone repository using https protocol. I've installed and configured the public cert on my side so the validity of server cert can be checked.
However, i'm having the following error when trying to clone:

```
% hg clone --verbose -- https://***/hg/Trainings/train-repo1 "c:\sandboxes\hg"
SSL error: wrong version number
[command returned code 255 Wed Nov 06 14:28:47 2013]
```

I guess I have to configure the SSL version supported on Tortoise side somehow, but cannot find resources on internet about how to do. I'm looking for any explanation or documentation on the subject. Tks !

*Note: the repo server force me to use https, and I have no control over it. (cannot switch to ssh)*

Comment: I confirm the problem, same happened to me since a couple of days with some minor differences: I specified the host's fingerprint in [hostfingerprints] section and my login credentials (Apache) in [auth] section. Using THg 3.0.2 including Hg 3.0.2.

Comment: Could you run the command with --debug and --traceback?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error message on an installation that had previously working without issue and no known changes to the server (which is under my control) or my local TortoiseHg install.

I tracked it down to having set the environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY for an unrelated program on my computer.

I fixed it by adding the following to mercurial.ini:

```
[http_proxy]
host = <proxy-server>
no = <mercurial host ip address>
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, I just updated TortoiseHG ([via web](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) or `choco install tortoisehg`), which in turn updated it's internal version of SSL, which I presume was so old bitbucket retired it.